# The best way to place two plots side by side

Tags: graphics, minipage, plot

I am wondering did I use the right code, because the plots are not placed right in the Latex. Any better idea?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=4.0in, height=2.7in] {temp.png}
\caption{Plot of hourly temperature from 2012-01-01 00:00 to 2016-06-13 23:00.} 
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=2.7in, height=2.7in]{LRtemp.png}
 \caption{Linear relationship between demand and temperature}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: They seem to be aligned on the baseline as you requested. What did you want to happen instead?

Comment: @cfr: *What* is aligned?

Comment: @cfr I would like both plots and the baseline to be alined, not just baseline.

Comment: Try to replace `\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}` with `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}`.

Comment: You can't have both as originally configured because the caption for one is one line longer than for the other. So if they are aligned on the baseline, the plots won't be, whereas if the plots are, the baselines won't be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some comments and observations, in no particular order:

- The instruction `\centering` has no effect as the two `minipage` environments are separated by `\hfill`. Just omit `\centering`.
- It may be more straightforward to set the widths of the two `minipage`s to an absolute size, say, `4in` and `2.7in`, respectively, and then set the widths of the graphics to `\linewidth`.
- A side-benefit of assigning absolute widths to the `minipage`s and relative widths to the included graphics is that the widths of the captions and graphics will coincide -- something that's decidedly not the case in the screenshot you posted.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage[margin=.5in,letterpaper]{geometry} % set page block parameters
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{2} % just for this example...
\setcounter{figure}{10}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\begin{minipage}[b]{4in}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=2.7in] {temp.png}
    \caption{Plot of hourly temperature from 2012-01-01 00:00 to 2016-06-13 23:00} 
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{2.7in}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=2.7in]{LRtemp.png}
    \caption{Linear relationship between demand and temperature}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```